# Buffer and erase vs buffer outside_only yielding different values in ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, buffer

I am using urban atlas polygon data and wish to make a hollow buffer ring (of an arbitrary 10 m) around particular polygons.  There are two methods to do this, buffer with the setting "outside only", or buffer then erase.  I have done both of these and found that in some instances the resultant area of each method is slightly different.  I realise that buffer then erase will remove the buffer of separate polygons if they are within the buffer region, however in this example it is an isolated polygon and therefore cannot be the reason.

[image]

The figure shows an example of the polygon with the buffer.  The top attribute table (buffer_outside) is the area of the buffer by using the "outside_only" method.  The erase value is the area from using buffer then erase tools.  "Shape_Area" is an inbuilt function of the data which displays the area of the polygon and is non-editable.  To save this value, I create another column and calculate the area separately using the "calculate geometry" tool as a float.  Aside from this, all other settings are default and therefore should be equal.  Despite the funny shape of this example polygon, this issue occurs in very regular (rectangular) polygons as well.

I realise the difference is very small, but why is this happening?

Comment: You may want to check vertex counts during the steps: https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000011230  Just a guess here.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Looking at each step individually there are differences (logically), therefore I can understand how this causes my issue.  Unfortunately I do not think that this can be avoided because of the nature of the operations?